# ESRI Maps with RaVis VisualGraph

Tags: esri-geodatabase

How can we integrate ArcGIS maps with RaVis BirdEye's VisualGraph?
My intention is to place the RaVis VisualGraph over the map and the nodes of the visual graph  must be placed on their specific location on the map...

Can anybody help me in this regard?